# How to add new data to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want add new data to my numpy array. here is the example of my array.

```
A = np.array([
    [4.752735, 1.16801, -3.9976401, -0.319121, -7.4322705, -3.8692],
    [5.2125, 1.165454, -3.99143, -0.318649, -7.43615, -4.12229],
    [5.16795, 1.083616, -3.9877, -0.315453, -7.43191, -3.97633],
    [4.660315, 0.89965, -3.98708, -0.321073, -7.41803, -3.69156],
    [4.839925, 0.93606997, -3.9822102, -0.315018, -7.41289, -3.79918],
    [4.711875, 1.143996, -3.98545, -0.304904, -7.4152703, -3.90752]
    ])

B = np.array([
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
])
```

How to Add B each 2 iteration on A.

expected A after add B:

```
array([
    [4.752735, 1.16801, -3.9976401, -0.319121, -7.4322705, -3.8692],
    [5.2125, 1.165454, -3.99143, -0.318649, -7.43615, -4.12229],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [5.16795, 1.083616, -3.9877, -0.315453, -7.43191, -3.97633],
    [4.660315, 0.89965, -3.98708, -0.321073, -7.41803, -3.69156],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [4.839925, 0.93606997, -3.9822102, -0.315018, -7.41289, -3.79918],
    [4.711875, 1.143996, -3.98545, -0.304904, -7.4152703, -3.90752]
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    ])
```

I've try used this code but I want make it dynamic. because I want make the iteration dynamic. now I want each 2 iteration, maybe later I want make it each 50 iteration. here my code:

```
result = np.empty((0, A.shape[1]))

for i in range(0, A.shape[0], 2):
    result = np.vstack([result, A[i:i+2], B, B])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a big numpy array from smaller arrays requires you to copy all the data from the smaller arrays, so it's inefficient to keep building new arrays using `vstack` in a loop. Instead, pre-allocate a larger array, and then assign to the slices:

```
result = np.empty((A.shape[0] * 2, A.shape[1]))
result[::4] = A[::2]
result[1::4] = A[1::2]
result[2::4] = B
result[3::4] = B
```

---

Now, to soft-code the frequency and number of `B` rows, you need to first calculate the size of the new array. Since we add `b_count` rows (from `B`) every `b_freq` rows of `A`, the `new_row_count` can be calculated as shown below:

```
b_freq = 3 # Add B every three rows
b_count = 2 # Add B 2 times every b_freq rows

old_row_count = A.shape[0]
new_row_count = old_row_count + int(np.ceil(old_row_count / b_freq) * b_count)

step = b_freq + b_count

result = np.empty((new_row_count, A.shape[1]))

# Set rows from A
for i in range(b_freq):
    result[i::step] = A[i::step]

# Set rows from B
for i in range(b_count):
    result[b_freq+i::step] = B
```

This gives the desired result:

```
[[ 4.752735   1.16801   -3.9976401 -0.319121  -7.4322705 -3.8692   ]
 [ 5.2125     1.165454  -3.99143   -0.318649  -7.43615   -4.12229  ]
 [ 5.16795    1.083616  -3.9877    -0.315453  -7.43191   -3.97633  ]
 [ 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.       ]
 [ 4.711875   1.143996  -3.98545   -0.304904  -7.4152703 -3.90752  ]
 [ 5.2125     1.165454  -3.99143   -0.318649  -7.43615   -4.12229  ]
 [ 5.16795    1.083616  -3.9877    -0.315453  -7.43191   -3.97633  ]
 [ 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.       ]]
```

---

Alternatively, create a *list* containing all the rows of the `result` array, and stack the rows into an array after you've finished making the list:

```
rows = []

for i in range(0, A.shape[0], 2):
    rows.extend([A[i:i+2], B, B])

result = np.vstack(rows)
```

---

With this method, soft-coding the frequency of `B` rows is easier since we don't need to pre-calculate the size of the new array: just change the step in the `range` of the for loop.

```
b_freq = 3  # Add B every three rows
b_count = 2 # Add B 2 times every b_freq rows
rows = []

for i in range(0, A.shape[0], b_freq):
    rows.append(A[i:i+b_freq])
    rows.extend([B] * b_count)

result = np.vstack(rows)
```

Which gives two zero rows every three rows:

```
[[ 4.752735    1.16801    -3.9976401  -0.319121   -7.4322705  -3.8692    ]
 [ 5.2125      1.165454   -3.99143    -0.318649   -7.43615    -4.12229   ]
 [ 5.16795     1.083616   -3.9877     -0.315453   -7.43191    -3.97633   ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 4.660315    0.89965    -3.98708    -0.321073   -7.41803    -3.69156   ]
 [ 4.839925    0.93606997 -3.9822102  -0.315018   -7.41289    -3.79918   ]
 [ 4.711875    1.143996   -3.98545    -0.304904   -7.4152703  -3.90752   ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
```